# "bootRun" task in Gradle - FAILURE: Build failed with an exeption

Tags: java, gradle

I am follwoing this tutorial 
https://auth0.com/blog/integrating-spring-data-jpa-postgresql-liquibase/
at the moment. 
But I have some problems with Gradle... Everytime when I try to run the project with "./gradlew bootRun" it returns an error:

```html
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished wit
h non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 44s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

I'm running Java 10.0.2 and Gradle 4.10.1.

I appreciate any kind of help!